# Deduping contacts in SQL. Two Databases. Select statements, joins and #TempTables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok, so two databases Person and Company.

-Select contacts WITHOUT all caps in Person.Pers_FirstName

-Select Company.Comp_companycode that have value of null (no assigned company code.)

I need to join them together on Person.Pers_CompanyID=Company.Comp_CompanyID

After I have that I need to be able to see the results, and then delete them. The fields I'll need to be able to see in the results are Person.Pers_FirstNAme and Person.Pers_LastName

Here's what I have so far

```
Select * from Person where Pers_FirstName != upper(Pers_FirstName) 
collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
into #TempTable1
select * from Company where comp_customernumber is null into #TempTable2

From #TempTable1, TempTable2
select #TempTable1.Pers_CompanyId, #TempTable2.Comp_CompanyId  FROM dbo.#TempTable1
inner join dbo.#tempTable2 ON #TempTable1.Pers_CompanyID=#TempTable2.Comp_CompanyID
```

I'm getting errors at BOTH of my INTO commands. Naturally, the second block of code
referencing #temptable1 and #temptable2 are unable to be located.

---

```
Select * 
into #TempTable1
from Person 
where Pers_FirstName != upper(Pers_FirstName) 
collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

select *  
into #TempTable2
from Company 
where comp_customernumber is null


select Comp_CompanyId  FROM #TempTable2
inner join dbo.#tempTable1 ON #TempTable1.Pers_CompanyID=#TempTable2.Comp_CompanyID
```

SQL doesn't see any of my #temptable1 or #temptable2

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag to clarify the DBMS (due to the usage of `collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax is

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM Table;
```

In your case:

```
Select * 
into #TempTable1
from Person 
where Pers_FirstName != upper(Pers_FirstName) 
collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

select *  
into #TempTable2
from Company 
where comp_customernumber is null
```

EDIT: add Select statement

```
select t1.Pers_CompanyId, t2.Comp_CompanyId  
FROM #TempTable1 t1
    inner join #tempTable2 t2 
        ON t1.Pers_CompanyID=t2.Comp_CompanyID
```

EDIT2: How to drop temp tables

You need to run this before

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempTable2 ', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #tempTable2 


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tempTable1 ', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #tempTable1
```

Comment: Thanks so much, and yet I think I'm still to daft to figure out how to use  'select' to 'inner join'. `
select Comp_CompanyId  FROM #TempTable2
inner join dbo.#tempTable1 ON #TempTable1.Pers_CompanyID=#TempTable2.Comp_CompanyID
` returns all errors trying to find any data

Comment: @dannyBwheeler I just edited the answer. Tell me the error you find, is any. And how are you thinking of deleting rows, by hand?

Comment: I get "Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named '#TempTable1' in the database."

Comment: @dannyBwheeler You need to drop it before creating. I just add the code needed.